If $\textbf{x}$ is not free in $\textbf{A}$, show that $\vdash\exists\textbf{x}\textbf{A}\leftrightarrow\textbf{A}$
Let $A$ be a formula in a theory $T$. Then $\vdash_{T}\exists xA$ certainly shouldn't imply $\vdash_{T}A$ if $x$ is free in $A$, but I don't see what's wrong with the following proof.
$\textbf{Lemma}$. If $\vdash_{T}A$ and $\vdash_{T}B$, then $\vdash_{T}A\rightarrow B$.
$\textbf{Proof of Lemma}$. Let $T'$ be the theory obtained by adding new constants $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ such that $A[e_{1},...,e_{n}]$ is closed. Then by the deduction theorem and the theorem on constants (see Shoenfield, page 34) $\vdash_{T}A\rightarrow B$ iff $\;\vdash_{T'[A[e_{1},...,e_{n}]]} B[e_{1},...,e_{n}]$. But by the theorem on constants, $\vdash_{T}B\Rightarrow\;\vdash_{T'}B[e_{1},...,e_{n}]\Rightarrow\;\vdash_{T'[A[e_{1},...,e_{n}]]} B[e_{1},...,e_{n}]$.
$\textbf{Proof of Claim}$. By the generalization theorem, if $\vdash_{T}\neg A$, then $\vdash_{T}\forall x\neg A$. Hence by the lemma, the definition of $\forall$, and the tautology and equivalence theorems, $\vdash \neg A\rightarrow\forall x\neg A\Rightarrow\;\vdash \neg A\rightarrow\neg\exists x A\Rightarrow\;\vdash\exists x A\rightarrow A$.

It may help to make explicit the existence of a non-empty domain of discourse. If, for example, we assume $\exists x: D(x)$, then it will be easy to prove $\exists x: [D(x) \land A] \iff A~~$ (only 12 lines using a form of natural deduction).

Note that in the empty domain $\top$ is true and $\exists x. \top$ is false. To even mention $A[x/a]$ you need to have some term $a$ lying around.

The question as written is not at all clear. What is the Claim whose proof  you're asking about?
My interpretation is as follows. You have been assigned to prove that if $x$ is not free in $A$, then $\vdash \exists x A\leftrightarrow A$ (which is a true statement). In the course of trying to prove this, you've come up with a "proof" that $\vdash \exists x A\to A$ which doesn't seem to use the hypothesis that $x$ is not free in $A$ (and indeed this statement is typically false when $x$ is free in $A$). And you want to know what is wrong with your proof. Is my interpretation correct? Your question should make this more clear. In particular, the title is misleading, since it's not what you're asking about. A better title would be something like "What is wrong with my proof of $\vdash \exists x A\to A$?", and then you could move the problem statement that's currently in the title into the body of the question to give some context for how the question arose.
In any case, there's nothing wrong with the proof written in "Proof of Claim", but it begins with the hypothesis that $\vdash \lnot A$. So what you've shown is that if $\vdash \lnot A$, then $\vdash \exists x A\to A$. Which is true even if $x$ is free in $A$.
I suspect what went wrong here is that you interpreted your Lemma to say the following: If $\vdash A$ implies $\vdash B$, then $\vdash A\to B$. This is wrong, and it's not what your Lemma says.
By the way, the statement of your Lemma is correct, but it includes a superfluous hypothesis. In fact, if $\vdash B$, then $\vdash A\to B$, regardless of what $A$ is.

The title of the question is only related to what I proved insofar as it lead me to thinking about the claim which I did "prove"

@SihOASHoihd Right, and that's why it's great motivation (if explained in the question) but not a good title.

I will change it, thanks for the suggestion. The claim I attempted to prove is $\vdash\exists xA\rightarrow A$, which I know is incorrect when $x$ is free in $A$ but I wasn't sure why. If I have $\vdash\neg A\rightarrow\forall x\neg A$ then I can prove my claim. But it looks like the issue is that I cant get this without assuming $\vdash\neg A$.

is there a simple counterexample for "if $\vdash A$ implies $\vdash B$, then $\vdash A\rightarrow B$"?

@SihOASHoihd Sure: the one in your question! $\vdash A$ implies $\vdash \forall x A$, but $\not\vdash A\to \forall x A$.

@SihOASHoihd Or, for an example with no free variables: let $P$ be a proposition symbol. Then $\not\vdash P$ and $\not\vdash\lnot P$. We have $\vdash P$ implies $\vdash\lnot P$ (since $\not \vdash P$), but $\not\vdash P\to \lnot P$ (since $P\to\lnot P$ is equivalent to $\lnot P$).

@PW_246 My answer is not intended to be cruel, nor is it grammatically incorrect. Please do not make trivial edits.

@AlexKruckman sentences don’t start with ‘and’. If you can’t tell when you’re being demeaning, then I hope on everything you don’t teach even (or especially) at the high school level. People like you are the reason 5 yr. olds end up with crippling math anxiety. It’s not that big of a deal. Take a deep breath before you criticize someone’s question. Almost no one that asks Logic questions on this site has even a bachelor’s degree in math. This site is not for answering questions, but stroking O.G.s’ egos.

@AlexKruckman if the Principle of Charity doesn’t exist on this site, then this site shouldn’t exist. Also, parts of your critique weren’t even accurate. The title is clearly what OP is asking about, unless you literally have no capacity for forming a theory of mind about other minds.

@AlexKruckman how do I prove that $\vdash A\rightarrow\forall xA$ is not a theorem in general? Presumably I could find a model in which it is not valid, but I admit that, while I understand I made an unjustified assumption, that assumption still looks like it should be true to me.

Take A = "x is even" and apply soundness.

@NaïmFavier I think could also use the example in N that $\vdash x=0$ implies $\vdash y=0$ but obviously $x=0\rightarrow y=0$ is not a theorem of N, right?

@PW_246 Not everyone agrees about that.... How about applying the Principle of Charity to my answer, which was a well-intentioned clarification and critique of the way the question was asked? To SihOASHoihd, I hope you did not find my post demeaning. If I misinterpreted your question, please let me know.

@AlexKruckman I have literally no reason to think that responses like yours are in good faith, since almost every question on this site is picked apart like vultures at a carcass. Also, I was being charitable by just editing it for you and leaving the remakes in the notes, as opposed to just commenting.
